# How do I use Postman or apidog for bitso API withdrawal

Tags: http, postman

I generated API keys from bit-so and tried adding the API key to the header as `api_key` and `api_secret`, then I added the request body, but when I send the request, I get a 401 authorisation error then when I set host header to https://bitso.com/ I get a 400 error. How do I fix this?

I'm not too familiar with HTTP requests and all that but I have API dog set up and my API keys exported. How do I send a withdrawal request to bit-so API using API dog?